# What is the lifetime of Tensor data accessed (e.g. flat() or vec()) inside a Compute method?

Tags: tensorflow

If I am inside the Compute() method of an OpKernel and access the input tensor, using, e.g:

```
auto data = context->input(0).vec<string>();
```

What is the lifetime of `data` ? Can I store that object in a class state variable and expect the data to remain valid on subsequent runs?

If not, what is the correct memory management technique for copying the data?

A pointer to an example would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The `data` object is an `Eigen::TensorMap<string, 1>`, which contains a *borrowed* pointer to the raw buffer in a [`tensorflow::Tensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/cc/ClassTensor.html) object. You must ensure that the `tensorflow::Tensor` object is not destroyed. The easiest way to do this is to store the `tensorflow::Tensor` as the member variable on your class. (A `tensorflow::Tensor` itself contains a reference-counted buffer, so it is relatively cheap to "copy" an object of that type.)